# Java- Returns incorrect values while working with multidimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, minesweeper

I am working on Minesweeper game, and every thing looked fine, exactly till yesterday's morning: I got a problem which I can not solve by my own. 
The situation looks like this: **I got 2 two-dimensional arrays**, in one i have generated Minesweeper field with all values generated, where **9 means bomb**, and **0 means free space**. Lets call it **field**. It is an integer array. Basically it is 9x9 field. It has +1 row of zeros as a frame for a proper work of code. Otherwise it returns *OutOfBoundsError* when running code listed bellow.
Example:

```
00000000000 0
00000019100 1
01110011100 2
02910000000 3
09321110000 4
02911910000 5
01111111110 6
01110112910 7
02920192110 8
02920111000 9
01110000000 10
00000000000 11
```

My second array is String array **user_field** and it is blank (all `null` field are replaced with `.`), here by entering commands user will open `.` fields.

```
........... 1
........... 2
........... 3
........... 4
........... 5
........... 6
........... 7
........... 8
........... 9
........... 10
........... 11
........... 12
```

It must output me on start all 0 from **field**, and all values around them. Example:

```
nnn 1
n0n 2
nnn 3
```

I use this code to call it:

```
       for (int i = 1; i < field_h-2; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < field_w-2; j++) {
                if (user_field[i][j]==null) {
                    user_field[i][j]=".";
                }
                if(field[i][j]==0) {
                    for(int k = 0; k< 3; k++) {
                        for (int n = 0; n< 3; n++) {
                            user_field[i-1+k][j-1+n] = String.valueOf(field[i-1+k][j-1+n]);
                            //System.out.print(String.valueOf(field[i-1+k][j-1+n]));
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.print(user_field[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println(" "+ (i));
        }
```

But in reality, it outputs (**n**-means value, **x**-means nothing.):

```
xxx 1
x0n 2
nnn 3
```

I don't have any ideas why this happens. Can someone help me please? I am not so experienced in Java, maybe I don't understand something.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve].

Comment: Also, it's not clear what your comment means - but you can edit your post if it doesn't say what you wanted it to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will explain the problem only considering the second line (the one that is `x0n`), but my reasoning applies to the previous and next line naturally.

Your program does this:

1. Originally `user_field` is `xxx`, and `field` is `n0n` (let's say it's `102`).
2. You look at the first element of `field`. It is `1`, and as such it is not `0`, so you do not make any changes to `user_field`. Then you immediately print first element of `user_field`, which at that point is still `x`. So so far you printed `x`.
3. You move to the second element of `field`. It is zero, so you update first and third elements of `user_field`. But at that point **you already printed the first element of `user_field`**. Now `field` is `102`, `user_field` is `102`, but you have already printed `x`. Now you print the second element of `user_field`, so you end up printing `x0`.
4. You move to the third element of `field`. It is not `0`, so you make no changes. You print the third element of `user_field`, which at this time is `2`, so you end up printing `x02`, while the desired output is `102`.

To fix it, split your loop in two. In the first loop compute `user_field`, and in the second loop print it. Something along the lines of:

```java
   for (int i = 1; i < field_h-2; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < field_w-2; j++) {
            if (user_field[i][j]==null) {
                user_field[i][j]=".";
            }
            if(field[i][j]==0) {
                for(int k = 0; k< 3; k++) {
                    for (int n = 0; n< 3; n++) {
                        user_field[i-1+k][j-1+n] = String.valueOf(field[i-1+k][j-1+n]);
                        //System.out.print(String.valueOf(field[i-1+k][j-1+n]));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

   for (int i = 1; i < field_h-2; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < field_w-2; j++) {
            System.out.print(user_field[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println(" "+ (i));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly. Good luck to you!